# Unable to click invisible select python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve all possible lists from [this website](https://www.osram-americas.com/en-us/applications/automotive-lighting-systems/Pages/lrgmain.aspx)

Model will only open when year is selected. Similarly Make will only open when Model is selected. I want to store all combination of Year, Model and Make for learning purpose.

However I am not able to click year field only. It seems it is hidden and without this I can't go ahead with rest of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.osram-americas.com/en-us/applications/automotive-lighting-systems/Pages/lrgmain.aspx")
# Switch to new window opened
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# Close the new window
driver.close()
# Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

el = driver.find_element_by_id('sbToggle_27562807')
el.click()
```

It gives error :-

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"sbToggle_27562807"}

Comment: Are you sure this I'd `sbToggle_27562807` for element is fixed?? I think it's dynamically generated. Verify it and try with some different locator or share here HTML as well for better solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"sbToggle_27562807"}

`year` element is not hidden, actually your locator to locate element using `find_element_by_id('sbToggle_27562807')` is not correct. In this element `id` attribute value is dynamically changing that's why you're unable to locate this element.

Instead of `id` locator you should try using some different locator. I would suggest, for better way try using `find_element_by_css_selector()` as below :-

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#fldYear a.sbToggle")
el.click()
```

Comment: can you let me know how to select value from it - i.e. 2016

Comment: This is another question, so please ask another question regarding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The element IDs change on each reload of the page, you'll have to find a different way to find the dropdown.

You can always find the `<a>` link with the "-- Select Year --" text, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS selector to get to the arrow pointing downwards on the select year dropdown

```
"div[id='fldYear'] > div[class='sbHolder'] > a[class='sbToggle']"
```

or this xpath

```
"//div[@id='fldYear']/div[@class='sbHolder']/a[@class='sbToggle']"
```

Click on this to webelement to get the options